# In Laravel Eloquent, why is this not selecting properly (no where condition)?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Using this:

`profile = User::find($user)->with('profile')->first();`

Will return  a query of `SELECT * FROM profiles`, instead of selecting the profile belonging to the id of the found user.

My user model is as follows:

```
public function profile() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\UserProfile', 'user_id');
}
```

Why is it not adding a `where` condition?

Comment: Have you tried to reorder them: `User::with('profile')->find($user)->first();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What `find($id)` really does is expand your query, like this:

```
// from
User::find($user)
// to
User::where('id', $user)->take(1)->get('*')->first()
```

In other words: it creates the query, limits it to the first row, gets that row - which returns a collection - and then returns the first item in that collection.

That means your `with('profile')` gets attached to the object, not to the query builder, and then you tack another `first()` call to that.

What you should do instead is

```
User::with('profile')->find($user);
```

... which I assume works but I haven't tested it. :)